# how to maintain appilcation state in windows in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

When i press a button in wpf I want a window to be opened after I came out of that form again when I press same button I want the state of the window to be maintained in windows presentation foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that `button_click` event create an object of new window like,

`NewWindow nw = new NewWindow()`;

then use `ShowDialog` to call new window.

```
nw.ShowDialog();
```

So the new window will open on top of the old one. When you close the new window, then you can continue in your old window with the same state.